# 4k samsung monitor issue with resolution

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, samsung, 4k-monitor, xorg.conf

I'm running Ubuntu 19.04 and I'm having an issue with getting my Samsung 32" ([U32J590](https://www.samsung.com/uk/monitors/uhd-u32j590/)) monitor to display anything better than full HD. Issue is with Linux only (I've tried it on Ubuntu 18.04 as well), works perfectly with Windows.

### Things I've tried so far

So far i tried adding q resolution for this monitor using `xrandr`, but it have not worked. When I applied new resolution all sorts of issue came up, **i.e.** like the screen was fully visible, but the mouse cursor would only be moving in 75% of the screen, the rest of the screen was not accessible with the cursor, or sometimes it didn't allow me to change it at all. Some other times, when I rebooted my PC, it kept giving me a black screen with the terminal saying `Can't Open Display`.

---

One person in [Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2418952&p=13862468#post13862468) suggested that I need to set up xorg config myself, but how can I do this for my monitor?

---

MSI GL62-6QD
Nvidia gtx950m
thanks for your reply. the monitor is  Samsung 32 Inch U32J590   and im running ubuntu 19.04 same happened on 18.04. . So far i tried adding q resolution for this monitor using xrandr, but it have not worked. When i applied new resolution all sorts of issue came up ie the screen was fully visible put mouse would only be moving in 75%of the screen  the rest of the screen was not acceasible with a cursor.  or sometimes it didnt allow to change at all. other times i rebooted  the pc and it kept giving me black screen with the terminal saying Cant Open Display.

Comment: Hi @badziobw and welcome to AskUbuntu. To improve your chances of getting an answer, please submit your TV's model, the Ubuntu version, and describe in detail what have you tried so far (share any packages you've installed, or bash scripts that you executed)

Comment: Hi , thanks for your reply. the monitor is  Samsung 32 Inch U32J590   and im running ubuntu 19.04 same happened on 18.04. . So far i tried adding q resolution for this monitor using xrandr, but it have not worked. When i applied new resolution all sorts of issue came up ie the screen was fully visible put mouse would only be moving in 75%of the screen  the rest of the screen was not acceasible with a cursor.  or sometimes it didnt allow to change at all. other times i rebooted  the pc and it kept giving me black screen with the terminal saying Cant Open Display.

Comment: I meant that you need to update your original post with the additional information (I did it for you). I hope some of the members of our community will be able to help you. Best of luck.

Comment: Can you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1147413/4k-samsung-monitor-issue-with-resolution) your question (don't post comment or answer though) add put in your computer make and model as well as your graphics card make and model.